# How to edit text which displays in a column

Tags: formula

On a report, there is a column which has very long text, with prefixes of 'Partner Programme'

How can I remove the prefix of 'Partner Programme' so that when displayed on a Dashboard, only the text which I want to view is visible?

Comment: This question is hard to understand. Maybe some screenshots would help clear it up

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -3):

You can do the followig:

1. Create a formula field and trim the value based on your requirement
2. Use formula field for reports

Let me know if this helps

Comment: This answer needs additional details to be useful.